# Fetch Scan by ID returns Empty JSON on VScanner

Tags: json, curl

I've successfully initiated a scan using the VScanner API and I have the enqueued_scan_id. When I try to fetch the results, I'm getting an empty JSON object. Here's my CURL request:

```
curl --location 'https://api.vscanner.ai/v1/api/scan/' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer my_actual_api_key'
```

Any thoughts? I've been going over docs.vscanner.ai